# Question about Jesus and a book

Tags: life-of-jesus

Muslims says Jesus gave a book when he came as prophet and then over time Christians corrupted that book is that true?

Comment: Your question is basically the same as "Christians, is the entire foundation of your religion wrong because another religion says so?" What kind of answer do you expect?! Of course Christians don't accept what Islam says about it! Just as Muslims don't accept what Christianity says about Islam.

Comment: Stack Exchange, as a platform, expects academic questions which are already researched and which provide sufficient clarity and detail for them to be sensibly answered. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of this, particular _comparative Christianity_ site.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that Muslims believe the Gospel message, written down, has long been corrupted by Christians. Here is what a scholar has explained in his book below, which might give you a basis for further research so that you can go on to ask further questions, better suited to this Christianity site.

> "The writings of the Old Testament, the Gospels and the Epistles, all
> represent vicarious experiences retold at second, third, or fourth
> hand by their authors with an additional reworking by redactors and
> editors.
>
> Within the New Testament are four Gospels, utterly incomprehensible to
> Muslims, since **the Gospel entrusted by God to Jesus was reputedly a
> single Book.** The conclusion derived by Muslims is that because there
> are four, none of them are valid or reliable. In fact, the popular
> Islamic explanation is that the early Christian community lost the
> original Gospel received from Jesus and set about to make good the
> deficiency, by substituting for one sequential account an intricately
> woven fabric of writings and traditions of many periods and different
> generations. Thus, according to Muslims, the teachings of Jesus might
> now be irretrievably lost to posterity were it not that their
> substance is reserved in the Qur'an." *Islam: the way of submission*
> Solomon Nigosian (Crucible, 1987) last chapter, 'Islamic Understanding
> of Christianity'

That is truly ironic, given that there are only 25 verses in the entire Qur'an that speak of Jesus! The scholar goes on:

> "Muslims argue that Christians and Jews were not fit custodians of
> their own Holy Books and that they tampered with them in various ways,
> particularly by **suppressing or obscuring what otherwise would have
> confirmed Islam and the true nature and identity of the Qur'an.**
> Stated differently, the Islamic view is that the content of Christian
> Scriptures does not match the content of the Qur'an; in their original
> form they did match. **The original form is irrecoverable** and corruption
> has occurred in the present versions." *(Ibid. Bold emphases mine)*

I recommend you obtain this scholar's book as it is an excellent, objective examination of Islam. Certainly his last chapter would give much more substance to the two short quotes I have made from it.

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: @john  Muslims speak of "The Injil", meaning the original Gospel Jesus gave to the Jews. It would have been accurate, but it was lost, they say, and Christians set about doing their own writing (including the 4 gospel accounts of the N.T.) These are viewed as corrupt and NOT the Injil God gave. Islamic written sacred scripture claims that Allah gave them "the Book" meaning the Qur'an, in Arabic. The writing of the Islamic Injil began around 650, 600 years after Jesus' death and resurrection (which they deny happened). See Qur'an 3:2, 5; 5:72; 10:37; 42:5; 43:1 & 57:26.